# WINAPI C++ Get current physical drive number

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a function

```
DWORD GetPhysicalDriveSerialNumber(UINT nDriveNumber, CString& strSerialNumber)
{
    DWORD dwResult = NO_ERROR;
    strSerialNumber.Empty();

    // Format physical drive path (may be '\\.\PhysicalDrive0', '\\.\PhysicalDrive1' and so on).
    CString strDrivePath;
    strDrivePath.Format(_T("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive%u"), nDriveNumber);

    // call CreateFile to get a handle to physical drive
    HANDLE hDevice = ::CreateFile(strDrivePath, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hDevice)
        return ::GetLastError();

    // set the input STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY data structure
    STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY storagePropertyQuery;
    ZeroMemory(&storagePropertyQuery, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY));
    storagePropertyQuery.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;
    storagePropertyQuery.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;

    // get the necessary output buffer size
    STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER storageDescriptorHeader = { 0 };
    DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;
    if (!::DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
        &storagePropertyQuery, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY),
        &storageDescriptorHeader, sizeof(STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER),
        &dwBytesReturned, NULL))
    {
        dwResult = ::GetLastError();
        ::CloseHandle(hDevice);
        return dwResult;
    }

    // allocate the necessary memory for the output buffer
    const DWORD dwOutBufferSize = storageDescriptorHeader.Size;
    BYTE* pOutBuffer = new BYTE[dwOutBufferSize];
    ZeroMemory(pOutBuffer, dwOutBufferSize);

    // get the storage device descriptor
    if (!::DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
        &storagePropertyQuery, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY),
        pOutBuffer, dwOutBufferSize,
        &dwBytesReturned, NULL))
    {
        dwResult = ::GetLastError();
        delete[]pOutBuffer;
        ::CloseHandle(hDevice);
        return dwResult;
    }

    // Now, the output buffer points to a STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR structure
    // followed by additional info like vendor ID, product ID, serial number, and so on.
    STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR* pDeviceDescriptor = (STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR*)pOutBuffer;
    const DWORD dwSerialNumberOffset = pDeviceDescriptor->SerialNumberOffset;
    if (dwSerialNumberOffset != 0)
    {
        // finally, get the serial number
        strSerialNumber = CString(pOutBuffer + dwSerialNumberOffset);
    }

    // perform cleanup and return
    delete[]pOutBuffer;
    ::CloseHandle(hDevice);
    return dwResult;
}
```

I want to get current drive number(drive number of program located in)
Example(for my system):
If i will run porgram on disk c it must return 0(hdd 0)
If i will run progrman on disk d or e it must return 1(hdd 1)
Flash drive 2 etc.
How can I do this?

Comment: This is quite a bit of code... Can you be more specific where the problem is? This will increase the chance somebody will be able to provide a useful answer (unlike this one)

Comment: I added this code just in case for people to understand why I want to send drive number in function(To get serial number by drive id)Ideally I would like to do something like this GetPhysicalDriveSerialNumber(DRIVE NUMBER GETED BEFORE FUNCCCALLED,Str_to_save_hhd_serial_numb)

Comment: what if your programs runs from location similar to this `\\servername\sharename`?